# How many party members are there in Dragon Age 2?

Tags: dragon-age-2

So far I have discovered only four: Varric, Bethany, Aveline and Merril. Are there any more?

Comment: There are more than the ones you found yet, but I'm not far enough to give you a complete list.

Comment: @everyone: It would be nice if you kept the answers spoiler-free. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are 10: 6 mandatory, 2 optional, and 2 via DLC/Signature Edition.

#### Mandatory

These companions you get along the way of the main quest line:

> **Bethany and Carver:** acquired at the start of the game

> **Aveline:** acquired during the Prologue

> **Varric:** acquired at the start of Act I

> **Anders:** In Act I, after *Tranquility* quest

> **Merrill:** In Act I, after *Long Way Home* quest

#### Optional

These companions require you doing something extra to secure them:

> **Isabela:** Complete *Fools Rush In* quest

> **Fenris:** Complete *A Bitter Pill* quest

#### DLC/Signature Edition

You get these through DLC (or the Signature Edition, which includes some DLC):

> **Sebastian:** Acquired through *The Exiled Prince* DLC

> **Mabari Warhound:** Acquired through *The Black Emporium* DLC. Acts as a fifth party member like Ranger pets did in Dragon Age Origins, not a full-fledged companion.

Comment: There is also an ally from The Exiled Price DLC.

Comment: @David you're right: one of the allies I had under optional should be under DLC. Fixed.

Comment: To meet Fenris you must do the "bait and switch" quest