# Dragon Age 2 - Choosing a Character Class

Tags: dragon-age-2

I am deciding on which class I want to play in Dragon Age 2. Originally i chose a male warrior and was going to be a Tank. But now I see that Aveline is a tank and is one of the major characters in the game. So, other than a tank, what class is a good choice?

- Mage DPS
- Mage Healer
- Rogue Dual Blade
- Rogue Archer
- Warrior Two Hand DPS

Comment: Not possible to objectively answer this question. You'll get party members to fill every possible niche (and more). It's up to you to play how you want.

Comment: Best for what exactly? Please edit your question accordingly :)

Answer (score 4):

Over the course of the core game (not counting DLC) you will gain [companions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18023/how-many-party-members-are-there-in-dragon-age-2) to fill the following roles, which basically cover all the standard choices.

The roles of the companion mages are a bit blurred, because you can hugely change their role with the relevant abilities, but their specialisations become the guide. The other classes of companion are locked to specific weapon types (and should probably only take the expected role for that type).

- Warrior Two Handed *or* Mage (~Any)
- Warrior Weapon & Shield
- Warrior Two Handed *[optional]*
- Rogue Archer
- Rogue Dual Wield *[optional]*
- Mage (~Damage)
- Mage (~Healer)

As such, I'd recommend you **play as whatever class you want to be, because you're going to be duplicating a companion whatever happens** - and this doesn't really matter, there are few sections of the game where you're *required* to have a specific companion with you (usually only the companion quests and a few major plot points).

Answer (score 1):

Warrior would be fine. You can complete the game with any class, since you'll have more than enough help available.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is subjective, I suggest using the Rogue class. It's got a good balance of damage vs speed of movement in the field. The Stealth ability will come in handy, it basically works like WoW's stealth, where you use a powder to disappear.